# Is it intelligent to redline the CPU through Task.Run

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, performance, async-await

I know its bad for the Performance of my application to create too many threads (threadstarvation) but I'm not sure how this translates to the Async/Await functionalities. I understand Task.Run() uses the ThreadPool to execute its code. Also I read it doesn't allways create a new thread.

Now I have 3 points I coudln't find a answer to:

1. Do I need to make sure there aren't to many threads around by hand or will that be managed by the .Net-Framework?
2. Can this Code lead to threadstarvation?

   ```
   Dim ltsk As List(Of Task)
   For Each pers As Person In ListPerson 'Potentialy big Collection of Objects
      ltsk.Add(Task.Run(Sub() pers.CheckPerson))  'Long running function with own Task.Run() inside
   Next
   Task.WhenAll(ltsk)
   ```
3. Does this create a thread or not?

   ```
   Dim i As Integer = 0
   Task.Run(Sub() i += 1) 'I know its an insane example
   ```

I use Code similar to what I ask in (2.) in my new application and get a CPU usage of over 90%. Usualy when I get this high a usage I made something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Task Parallel Library (of which `Task` is a part) has several heuristics to prevent CPU starvation. In addition, Windows uses dynamic priorities which means if you're using thread pool threads to do CPU work, they will automatically run at a lower priority.

> 1. Do I need to make sure there aren't to many threads around by hand or will that be managed by the .Net-Framework?

It's managed by the framework.

> 2. Can this Code lead to threadstarvation?

No.

> 3. Does this create a thread or not?

It will queue a work item to the thread pool. If the thread pool has more work than it can do, it might decide to create another thread.

---

If you're doing actual parallel processing (CPU-intensive work), then you should consider using `Parallel` or Parallel LINQ instead of `Task` directly.

Comment: Thank you this clarified quiet a few things for me. What exactly is the benefit of using `Parallel` instead of handling the `Task` myself?

Comment: `Parallel` (and Parallel LINQ) have many higher-level constructs for things like "perform this operation on this sequence of inputs", "summarize the results", etc. With `Task` you'd have to do all of that by hand. e.g., `Parallel.ForEach(ListPerson, pers => pers.CheckPerson())`. Both `Parallel` and Parallel LINQ use "partitioning" to make the parallel code more efficient.